# DrawingSurface Draw event does not fire

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm working on a Silverlight application and am trying to use 3D support in my app. I have enabled 3D support with this line:

```
<param name="enableGPUAcceleration" value="true" />
```

Also, the application is running on localhost:80 via IIS and this has permission for 3D usage set to Allow.

I have a DrawingSurface in a xaml page and attached its Draw event in which I simply clear the surface to red. The Draw does not fire. So I tried invalidating the DrawingSurface on MouseLeftButtonDown. Here's some code:

```
        private void TestDrawing_Draw(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DrawEventArgs e)
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager.Current.GraphicsDevice.Clear(new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color(255, 0, 0));
    }

    private void TestDrawing_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (GraphicsDeviceManager.Current.RenderMode == RenderMode.Hardware)
        {
            TestDrawing.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Checking in debugmode, I find that the MouseLeftButtonDown event does fire. The GraphicsDeviceManager.Current.RenderMode is set to RenderMode.Hardware and the Invalidate() method is executed. But, the Draw event still does not fire.

I've created a testproject which runs via a Developer server on a specific port (50814). Again, enableGPUAcceleration is set to true and permission has been set to Allow. This testproject does fire the Draw event.

So... my large application, running on an IIS server (localhost:80) with enableGPUAcceleration set to true and permission set to Allow does not fire the Draw event. A simple testproject running a Developer server on port 50814 with enableGPUAcceleration set to true and permission to Allow does fire the Draw event.

I've no idea how to enable 3D for my application. Do you guys have any suggestions?!

Answer (score 0):

your code had the draw function working for only once, to make it work continuously, the draw event should be like this:

```
 public void drawingsurface_draw(object sender, DrawEventArgs e)
    {
    //do some thing here
    e.InvalidateSurface();
    }
```